# Redirecting a New Domain to Existing Subdirectory with WP Installation

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

after searching for a while I couldn't figure out how to solve this issue:

I have a client's website, say: client.com, which I am hosting as part of the company's website, company.com.

Client.com is currently permanently redirected to company.com.

I installed a wordpress site on company.com/client, and want client.com to point to the /client subdirectory, but keep client.com in the URL.

I was able to do this, but when I click one of the links on the client's website, like "About Us," it shows the new page, but stays at client.com instead of client.com/aboutus.

How can I make this happen? As in, how can I make the URL dynamic?

In the root directory of company.com I have the following .htaccess:

> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?client.com/$
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /client%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L]
> RewriteRule ^((?!client).*) /client%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
> ```

In the /client directory I have just the WP installed .htaccess:

> ```
> # BEGIN WordPress
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteBase /
> RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
> </IfModule>
>
> # END WordPress
> ```

Comment: How have you implemented the "permanent redirect"? If there was a "redirect" in place then you wouldn't see `client.com` at all. It sounds like you have some kind of "framed forwarding" set up (from where)? Do you have access to the server config? Or are you using a hosting control panel, like cPanel? You have some errors (or typos?) in the first `.htaccess` block - this would never work as written, please confirm?

Comment: I did it through the cPanel's DNS Manager.

Also, that's probably why it doesn't work correctly. I basically need a code that redirects client.com to company.com/client but keep the client.com URL. But it also has to change as the user clicks internal links.

Comment: "but stays at client.com instead of client.com/aboutus" - this suggests you have "framed forwarding" (or some kind of "masked redirect") - this has nothing to do with the code you posted. What exactly did you do in cPanel's DNS Manager? Is `client.com` already pointing to `company.com` in terms of DNS (`A` record or `NS` ?)

Comment: It is being frame forwarded, client.com's A record is forwarded permanently to company.com with masking.